# Need wildcard 301 redirect for WordPress on IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-config, iis-8, http-status-code-301

I'm running a WordPress blog on IIS. I currently have the permalinks for the articles set to:

/%postname%/%year%-%monthnum%-%day%/%hour%:%minute%

So a sample article would be, right now:

https://example.com/headline-here/2019-02-11/15:45

I now want to change the permalink URL to not have the time at the end, which I can set up in WordPress just fine. In fact right now if you go to

https://example.com/headline-here/

It actually works without changing anything.

However, when I change the permalink in WordPress, the old links with the time at the end no longer work. This is a problem for Google, since it'll see my whole indexed site as 404 page not found errors.

I want to put in a single rule in Web.Config that will redirect:

https://example.com/[ALL-HEADLINES]/* (anything after the headline being the "*")

To:

https://example.com/[ALL-HEADLINES]/ (basically redirecting as a permanent 301 when someone/Google links to the previous URL with the time) To be clear, if someone goes to:

https://example.com/headline-here/2019-02-11/15:45

They're automatically redirected to:

https://example.com/headline-here

Can I do this in Web.Config? Or can I do this in WordPress (I've tried, I think not).

I don't want any 404 errors. I want them all to be 301 permanent redirects.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Note, I have this installed, which allows for regular expressions, but I can't figure it out:  https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module